# Android how to pass set values to another activity?

Tags: android

In `Android` I want to pass set values to another `activity`..How Can I do that?

```
        Set<Person> persons=getPersons();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("persons", persons);  //Here I am getting error

        startActivity(intent);
```

But I am getting error in `intent.putExtra()`..why?how Can I pass these set values?

Comment: share your class Person's code.

Comment: you need to use paracable

Comment: persons is a set type and it will ask for primitive data typ

Comment: Use `HashSet ` instead of `Set`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use implement parcable in class Person

For example

```
public class Person implements Paracable{


}
```